# Multithreading function on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I have a function (angle_between) that takes two rows in pandas dataframe and then calculates the angle between them:

```
for i,vector_pair in enumerate(combos):
    angles.append(angle_between(vector_pair))
```

The combos list is a list of every pairwise pairing of rows in the pandas dataframe:

```
from itertools import combinations    
ixs = list(dataframe.index)
combos = list(combinations(ixs, 2))
```

Is there a way to mutlithread this process? My dataframe is ~35,000 rows, meaning theres something like 600 million comparisons, and am hoping to speed up the process.

Comment: Multithreading is a lost cause in Python for speed when it comes to CPU-bound tasks. Look into the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). `multiprocessing` can sometimes help, but the first port-of-call should be vectorization and, to attempt that, we need a repeatable example to play with. We can't see the function or data. Please given an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A [Dask DataFrame](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) might be a good way to do this. Dask will automatically parallelize as much as it can for you. The Dask API is almost exactly the same as Pandas', so it might fit your data well.

Comment: @natemcintosh In my testing of Dask, I'm yet to find anything that runs faster than the generic pandas/numpy solution when it's on a single PC. In that situation, it seems to be better just for bigger-than-memory problems